# Meaning of 'end up smoking something'?

Tags: meaning

I read an article, and it said

> In one critical way, Samsung's Galaxy S8 may end up smoking the
>   iPhone8 --a phone that's still months away from even being an official
>   thing.

What does 'end up smoking' mean? Overwhelmingly win on something? I searched at http://dictionary.cambridge.org/ but couldn't find any relevant one.

Comment: Well, since the Samsung unit is unlikely to take up puffing pot, it probably means it's going to "smoke" the iPhone unit in the sense that one hot rod racer "smokes" another -- leaving the losing unit behind in a cloud of smoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **smoking** in this case is being used as an idiom meaning "to beat the competition."

See [this definition](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/smoked) of "smoke" as an idiom:

> to beat someone in a contest; to outrun, outdistance, or outplay someone

So you are correct when you speculate that it means "overwhelmingly win."

And yes, as pointed out by Hot Licks in the comments, the term derives from the notion of "leaving one behind in your smoke," as in a race.

Comment: Appropriate username

Answer (score 0):

Smoke is being idiomatically here

***[Smoke](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/smoke)*** (Farlex)

> To beat someone in a contest; to outrun, outdistance, or outplay
>
> someone. e.g. :  Jill smoked Dave in the bicycle race.

To end up - means this will be the final result (the result in the end).

So the phrase is asserting that eventually the Samsung phone will outperferom or outsell the Apple phone.